# XE get started home page doesn't work after installing apex

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, localhost, port, oracle-apex

i've installed Oracle 11g on win10 64bit, the "XE get started" home page was working fine and then with some configurations i installed APEX and changed the port from 8080 to 8085. APEX home page is working correctly but not for "XE get started". tried to modify the URLs even for the html files in properties but that didn't work. any solutions please?

Answer (score 1):

Right; I found myself puzzled, probably as much as you (and some/many other people). Though, after performing several installations, I got used to it and I never cried much for that *cool* XE Homepage. Today, I'm quite happy with Apex' default appearance.

Anyway: there's a way to revert it back to what it was prior to Apex upgrade. A walkthrough is on Mike Smither's Blog, [Migrating the XE Database Management Application to a new version of APEX](https://mikesmithers.wordpress.com/2015/05/24/migrating-the-xe-database-management-application-to-a-new-version-of-apex/) (yes, a title sounds a little bit misleading, but - that's it).

Comment: Agreed and I wrote that home page. Use sqldev if you are looking for sessions,storage,...

Comment: You did? Whoa! Nice to meet you, then :)

Comment: I run a few things here at the big O :)